# How to make your css breakpoint work on mobile? (viewport meta tag already used)

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries, viewport

I am trying to get my media query of 360px to work on mobile devices, but it does not want to. It seems to work on desktop using dev tools to change it to a mobile view but it does not actually work on a phone.

I have already tried the viewport meta tag, I also tried changing the scaling and user scalability in the meta tag as well, I have tried changing the px size to see if it will work at a larger size and it does not work.

```
<!--HTML Meta Tag-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.5, user-scalable=yes" />

<!--Nav File Import Using php-->
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="navdiv">
<?php include("inc/Nav.php"); ?>
</div>

<div class="altdiv">
<?php include("inc/Altnav.php"); ?>
</div>
```

```
<!--Nav I Want To Show-->
<nav>
<div>
<ul class="navbar">

<!--Home-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="index.php" class="n">
//svg here
<label class="navbutton">Home</label></a></li>

<!--Events-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="events.php" class="n">
//svg here
<label class="navbutton">Events</label></a></li>

<!--News-->
<li class="navitem"><a href="blog.php" class="n">
//svg here
<label class="navbutton">News</label></a></li>

<!--More-->
<li class="navitem"><span class="n"><button type="button">
//svg here
<label class="navbutton">More</label></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

```
<!--CSS Code-->
//Does not show this
@media screen and (max-width : 360px) and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 4) {
    #wrapper {display:grid; grid-template-columns: auto; grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;}
    .navbar {display:grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto; grid-template-rows: auto; list-style:none; padding-left:0;}
    .navitem {display:flex; justify-content:center;}
    .n {display:flex; flex-direction:column; justify-content:center;}
    footer {text-align:center;}
    .footlink {display:flex; padding-left:0; justify-content:center;}
    .navdiv {display:none;}
    button {background-color:rgb(189,5,29); border:0;  padding:0;}
}

//Shows this
@media screen and (max-width : 750px) and (min-width: 361px) {
    .altdiv {display:none;}
    .navbar {display:flex; flex-direction:row; list-style:none;}
    .navitem {padding:1vw;}
}
```

I want it to show a different nav on a mobile screen but it is not scaling right so something I have not been able to figure out the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the more standard:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Yeah I have and it does not work. For some reason when I set my px to 3000px and not 360px it works on my phone.